# Envelope of a signal via Convex hull / Edge detection

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, lowpass-filter, amplitude

Is there a method in order to compute some sort of **edge detection** / **convex hull** of a signal `x[n]` (in orange here). Here of course the orange signal is not convex nor concave, but only piecewise...

(I would like to know if this could be an alternative way of computing the **envelope** of a signal, alternative to the traditional method `input -> abs() -> low pass filter`)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by edge detection?  Are you talking about running image processing on a plot of the signal?

Comment: @nispio In the 1-D context, the start/stop of a signal is what is usually meant as its 'edge'.

Comment: @nispio @user4619 I don't really know what I mean by edge detection ;) I used this word in order to speak about the orange curve in the previous example...

I wanted to know if there is another method for envelope than `input -> absolute value > low pass`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Hilbert transform to get the [analytic signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_signal).  The absolute value of the analytic signal is the envelope.  It's available in [SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hilbert.html) and many other software suites, though it's usually poorly named.